# Click ImageView which is inside a CollectionViewCell to go to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an ImageView inside a CollectionViewCell. I want to be able to click the image and it take me to another ViewController. How would I do this? This is the code I have so far.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var images = ["meal1", "photograph1", "meal1"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        //set images
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said you want to detect image tap on `collectionview` cell please go through this code :

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.connected(_:)))

    cell.yourImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.yourImageView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.yourImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

And add below method to your ViewController

```
func connected(_ sender:AnyObject){
     print("you tap image number : \(sender.view.tag)")
     //Your code for navigate to another viewcontroller
    }
```

**Note** - Make sure your user interection for cell image is enable

Answer (score 1):

Add a tabGestureRecognizer to your imageview in collectionView "cellForItemAt" method, and in the method of recognizer tap call the segue to go to the desired viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

**CollectionView Function:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)))

    cell.yourImg.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.yourImg.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.yourImg.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    return cell
}
```

**Tap Function:**

```
@IBAction func tap(_ sender:AnyObject){
    print("ViewController tap() Clicked Item: \(sender.view.tag)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either us a [UIButton and set the image property on it](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton) with no title, or you can add a [UIGestureRecognizer to the UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer). Either way, you'd just Present or Show the ViewController you want to display once the action has been received.

One thing I'll often do in this situation, is create a CollectionCellDelegate protocol that has a callback function (something like `buttonPressed:forCollectionCell:`), that I can have my CollectionView conform to, then set the delegate of each cell to the CollectionView. Then you can call up to the CollectionView when the button/image is pressed, and have the CollectionView handle whatever behaviour you want, in this case, presenting/pushing a new view controller.